# How to edit and restart and upstart job without rebooting?

Tags: upstart

I'm trying to deploy a WSGI appplication with Gunicorn.  I have written an upstart job for launching the WSGI app.

I'm testing different options (Unix socket v. TCP, etc).  Whenever I change the `.conf` file restarting the job does not see the difference.  How do I instruct upstart (the `service` program) to update its view about the conf file?